# Can security tokens (ST-20) and utility tokens (ERC-20) exists on same blockchain?

Tags: tokens, erc-20, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I am trying to build a dApp in which the functionalities of the dApp can be accessed by utility token but in the same app I wish to tokenize the securities as well. Can my utility tokens and the tokens which I am creating for secuties exists on the same blockchain?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After quite some googling it seems that ST-20 is a token standard created by PolyMath which runs on Ethereum.

So, both ST-20 and ERC-20 already run on the same blockchain. They are just different token standards.

Comment: PolyMath is in talks to launch their own blockchain.

Answer (score 0):

> security tokens (ST-20) and utility tokens (ERC-20) exists on same
>   blockchain?

Yes, Both can co-exist and run efficiently on same blockchain, infact St-20 is just an implementation of ERC-20 standards with some `overriding` methhods and addition of one key method `verifyTransfer` which was originally missing in ERC-20 standards.

**Remember ST 20 is a proprietary contract rule of [Polymath.Network](https://polymath.network/).**

More about [ST 20 implementation](https://blog.polymath.network/overview-of-the-st-20-interface-and-polymath-core-86bf64c8929) on KYA/AML .